# Text not displaying properly html5

Tags: html, jquery, css

I **VERY** recently got into coding, I've started making a, small, tiny, project which has a scoring system! Inside of the style part of the file I have this section of code:

```css
.score {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 5vw;
  postion: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<div class="score">Score: 0
  <div>
```

But inside the page the text isn't shown show in one line but instead

```
 Looks
 like
 This
```

Any help would be appreciated! It just bugs me how bad it looks.
Also inside of my scripts is this line of code:

```
jQuery(this).stop().animate({'top':'100%'},100, function(){
                    add = add - (-1);
                    jQuery('.score').html('Score: ' + add);
```

that is used to increase the score

Managed to recreate this:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" charset="UTF-8" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            body{ width:10%; height:100%; overflow:hidden; }
            
            .score{
                text-align:center;
                font-family:arial; 
                font-size:5vw; 
                postion:absolute; 
                right:5%;
                z-index:-2;
                }
        </style>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                var add = 0;
                });
                    jQuery(this).stop().animate({'top':'100%'},100, function(){
                        add = add - (-1);
                        jQuery('.score').html('Score: ' + add);
            
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="score">Score: <b>0</b></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: welcome. please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

```css
.score {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5vw;
}
.no-margin{
 margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="score">
   <h2 class="no-margin">score</h2>
   <h2 class="no-margin">0</h2>
<div>
```

Try this..!!

Comment: didn't work it made the characters bold but with the issue still existing and then when the score went up it just reverted to the old look

Comment: Could you please attach the screenshot how you want ?